# Using recursion to get the sum of a tree, but the root node won't add in Kotlin

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, binary-tree

I'm doing a question to get the sum of an entire tree through recursion, but the root node wont add with the child node. Now I'm aware that the root node is just a value while the child nodes are Tree nodes, so there not the same type.

```
class TreeNode<T>(var key: T){
    var left: TreeNode<T>? = null
    var right: TreeNode<T>? = null
}



fun treeSumR(root: TreeNode<Int>): Int{
    if (root == null) return 0
    return root.key + root.left?.let { treeSumR(it) } + root.right?.let { treeSumR(it) }
}



fun buildTree2(): TreeNode<Int>{
    val one = TreeNode(1)
    val two = TreeNode(2)
    val four = TreeNode(4)
    val eleven = TreeNode(11)
    val three = TreeNode(3)
    val four2 = TreeNode(4)

    three.left = eleven
    three.right = four
    eleven.left = four2
    eleven.right = two
    four.right = one

    return three

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the root node wont add with the parent node"? Any error messages? Or does it produce a different output than you expect?

Comment: I meant child nodes. My bad,made the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error on the `+` operators because you are adding a non-nullable `Int` (`root.key`) and *nullable* `Int?`s (the sums of the subtrees) together. The sums of the subtrees are nullable because you wrote `?.`. Its effect is that the whole expression of `root.left?.let { ... }` evaluates to null if `root.left` is null.

You can provide a default value for the expression when it is null by using the [elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator):

```
return root.key +
    (root.left?.let { treeSumR(it) } ?: 0) +
    (root.right?.let { treeSumR(it) } ?: 0)
```

However, since you are already checking if `root` is null and returning 0, a better way is to make `root` *actually* nullable, and pass `root.left` and `root.right` directly into it `treeSumR`:

```
//               notice the question mark here
//                              v
fun treeSumR(root: TreeNode<Int>?): Int{
    if (root == null) return 0
    return root.key +
        treeSumR(root.left) + // since treeSumR now takes a nullable node, you can directly pass the subtrees in
        treeSumR(root.right)
}
```

Comment: I did think of doing it the last way you presented. But the if statement doesn't register for some reason. which is why I had to do a work around and use the let scope on it. Thank you for the help.